# Javascript form blocking not working on call to second function

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Been struggling with this for over an hour cant see the woods from the trees now ..

Ive a form with a onSubmit that calls a verification function, but the form is always submitting and the page refreshing.

It works OK if the end of the verification function looks like

```
function verifycheck(){
 .... checking scripts that work ....
 if (!pass){
    alert("Un ou plus des l'elements requis ne sont pas remplier. SVP remplier, puis envoyer encore!")
    return false
 }else{
    return false
 } 
}
```

The form never submits as Id expect ...

However if I then try to push a successful verification to another function ..

```
function verifycheck(){
.... checking scripts that work ....
 if (!pass){
    alert("Un ou plus des l'elements requis ne sont pas remplier. SVP remplier, puis envoyer encore!")
    return false
 }else{
    sendformdata(form);
 } 
}

function sendformdata(form){
 return false
}
```

The form will submit and the page refresh.

WHY does moving the return to a second function cause the form to submit ?

the HTML looks like

```
<form id="signupform" action="" method="post" onSubmit="return verifycheck(this);">
```

Comment: Because the second function returns to the first, which doesn't "pass on" the return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**WHY does moving the return to a second function cause the form to submit?**

That's because the `verifyCheck` function now doesn't return anything anymore. Return values do not automatically 'bubble' up. To prevent submitting, you have to return false from verifyCheck by passing on the return value from `sendformdata`. To do that, change the line calling that function to:

```
return sendformdata(form);
```

so the total code becomes:

```
function verifycheck() {  
  .... checking scripts that work ....
  if (!pass) {
    alert("Un ou plus des l'elements requis ne sont pas remplier. SVP remplier, puis envoyer encore!")
    return false;
  } else {
    return sendformdata(form); // Change in this line.
  } 
}

function sendformdata(form) {
  return false;
}
```